# main thread continues to run even when command window closes

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-multithreading

Edit: Actually, execution does end eventually. However, there is a 6 second delay or so between when the window closes and when code execution actually terminates, a gap  that is not present when the code is run directly from the .py.

My program works as expected when I run the .py file directly. But when I convert it to a .exe using pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller timer.py --name=timer --onefile --icon=icon.ico --hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification
```

A new issue arises where even after the user closes the command line window, the sound effect is still heard and it is obvious that the program is still running.
How can I fix this?

Here is the source code for the program itself:

```
import time
import random
import winsound
import pathlib
import threading
from plyer import notification
from os import system
system("title " + "Timer")
path = pathlib.Path().resolve()
print(str(path))

def wait(waitTime):
    time.sleep(waitTime*60)
    notification.notify(title='Timer', message='Boinga coinga timer done', app_icon=None, timeout=90)

# Import the soundfiles


eMsg = ["Um, think you got a typo there, bud.", "Um...that's not a number...", "What do they even teach kids in school these days,  anyway?"]
waitTime = 1;

print("Greetings, human.")
print("Behold, the ultimate timer app.")
print("Unlike certain other timers I will not mention by name, this one will actually go off eventually.")
print("Yeah, Google sure is a great company.")
print("Anyway. So. You probably want to set a timer, right?")

flag = False
canContinue = False
while (True):
    print("How many minutes should I wait before I harass you?")

    waitTime = input()

    
    try:
        waitTime = float(waitTime)
        canContinue = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(random.choice(eMsg))
        continue
        flag = True
    
    if canContinue:
        if (flag):
            print("Now we're talking!")
            print("Timer set for " + str(waitTime) + " minutes.")
            print("See ya then!")
        else:
            print("Aight! See ya in " + str(waitTime) + " minutes, bud.")

        # Launch the ticking thread
        th2 = threading.Thread(target=wait, args=(waitTime), daemon=True)

        # Wait as per normal
        for i in range(0, int(60*waitTime)):
            time.sleep(1)
            f = str(path) + "\\sfx\\tick" + str(random.randrange(2,5))+".wav"
            #print(f)

            threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=(f, winsound.SND_FILENAME), daemon=True).start()
            print(i)
        print("Time's up!")
        notification.notify(title='', message="Time's up, asshat!", app_icon="icon.ico", timeout=90)
        print("Nice.")
        flag = False
```

Comment: That's how a daemon thread works.  If you don't want it to be independent, then don't make it a daemon.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists even if daemon=False in both lines where a thread is created.

Comment: `winsound.PlaySound` will play until the sound is finished.  Are you starting this by double-clicking a shortcut, or by running on the command line?

Comment: I've tried both running the .exe directly by double clicking it, or opening a new cmd line window, navigating to the folder, and running the .exe from the command window. I am pretty sure the problem isn't winsound.Playsound, because I hear about 5 ticks (separate audio files) from the time that I close the window to when the ticking stops.

Comment: From the documentation: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#bootloader it appears that 2 processes are launched, a bootloader and the child. You are probably closing the bootloader which doesn't close the child immediately. What happens if you add: `import psutil ; from os import getpid ; proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid()) ;` lines separated by semicolons ... then rather than `while(True)` use `while proc.parent() is not None`